# Concatenating sed commands

Tags: bash, sed

I have a .txt file and there are three sed commands that I am using to manipulate it. First I convert it to a .csv by substituting tabs for commas (A), then I remove lines 1-8 (B) and then remove a '# ' that is in the beginning of line 9 (C).

```
(A) sed 's/\t/,/g' individuals/$message/$message.txt > individuals/$message/$message.csv
(B) sed -i 1,8d individuals/$message/$message.csv
(C) sed -i 's/.\{2\}//' individuals/$message/$message.csv
```

Is there a better way to do it, maybe integrating these three commands into a single one? It doesn't need to be done using sed but it does need to be done via bash commands.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
# This data file generated by PLINK at: Mon Jul 11 16:18:56 2022
#
# Below is a text version of your data.  Fields are TAB-separated.
# Each line corresponds to a single SNP.  For each SNP, we provide its
# identifier, its location on a reference human genome, and the genotype call.
# For further information (e.g. which reference build was used), consult the
# original source of your data.
#
# rsid  chromosome  position    genotype
22:16050607G-A  22  16050607    GG
```

I deeply appreciate the help!

PS: Line 9 is the `# rsid chromossome...` one and it should be kept in the file, just without the `#`

Comment: It works right?  So what is the problem?  The best theoretical solution is sometimes not worth your time, use it and move on IMHO.  If you absolutely want 1 command, I would use `awk`.

Comment: `sed ... -e 's/...' -e '1,8d' -e '9s/...' ...`

Comment: How does (C) remove `#`?

Comment: But it deletes the first 2 characters of the line, no matter what they are, not just hash-space.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I missed that it doesn't only operate on line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple `-e` options to execute multiple `sed` commands in one call.

```
sed -e '1,8d' -e '9s/^# //' -e '9,$s/\t/,/g' "individuals/$message/$message.txt" > "individuals/$message/$message.csv"
```